# How can I match a filename containing an ID in a specific way?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I have image filenames and I'm trying to find them by some id(`$id`) that is contained in their names.

The filenames always have the same structure:

```
something-$id(optional: numbers)(optional: -something).jpg
```

Now I want to match all filenames, which contain the id and are in the format like above described.

I tried the following to find the id with `strpos()`:

```
$s = substr($file, strpos($file, $id), strlen($id));
```

But this also finds the id even if it has numbers in front of it, e.g. `$id = 230` and filenames contain `2230`. But as described in the format above there can't be any numbers before the id.

So can I do this without a regex to find filenames, which contain the id in that specific format or should I use a regex and if yes how?

Comment: Use a regex for it. You can test it here: https://regex101.com and also take a look at `\b` word boundaries, so you don't match `110` if you have `10`

Comment: I don't know regex, could it be done width substr?

Comment: Note really, since it won't be as flexible as a regex. And if you don't know regex, then the linked site above is perfect. Put your input into it, play around and always look at the explanation to the right side.

Comment: Where should I see how could I write regular expressions? For example to match ```-$id-```?

Comment: See: https://regex101.com/r/hX8qB8/1 I put some input strings into it, 2 lines which you want to match, if the id is 230 and 2 which you don't want to match. I started with adding the id into the regex, and now you can expand it, so that it matches the file name as you want to.

Comment: But how to write this in php - I tried with this: ``` $s = substr($file, strpos($file, $id), strlen($id));
    $pattern = '/-'.$id.'-/';
    if(preg_match($pattern, $s) ==0){```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98946/discussion-between-rizier123-and-mistery-girl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex is more flexible here, so something like this would work for you:

```
$pattern = "/^.*-$id(\d*)?(-.*)?\.jpg$/";
```

You then can simply use this together with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), e.g.

```
if(preg_match($pattern, $input)){
    //It matches
}
```